# AutoHotKey: remapping Alt+Shift+<plus> to \

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to have a autohotkey remap for Alt + Shift + nonnumpad_plus_sign (equivalent to Alt + ? in my keyboard) and have that send a backslash '\'

I've tried stuff like:

```
!+NumpadAdd::\
```

(which works, but I want to use the non-numpad + sign of the keyboard).

Also this works:

```
!+::\
```

(Alt + nonnumpad_plus_sign = \, but how can I have shift and + in the same line?)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Edit: the solution for my case following the steps in the answer below is

```
!+SC00C::Send, /
```

but also

```
!++::Send, /
```

works as well, perhaps more elegant solution (the first + represents Shift, the second the + sign)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click the <kbd>+</kbd> key on my keyboard I need to type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>.

Therefore <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> is remapped as follows:

```
!+=:: Send, \
```

If your keyboard is different, it might require a different combination.

For example, you may be able to define the key using its scan-code.
To find it out:

- Create a `.ahk` script containing this one line:

  ```
  #InstallKeybdHook
  ```
- Run the script
- Right-click its traybar icon (green H) and choose Open
- Click the menu *View > Key history and script info*
- Press the <kbd>+</kbd>
- Press <kbd>F5</kbd>
- Note the three-digits code that is next to the key

Assuming that the scan-code was `123`, the following script might work:

```
!+SC123:: Send, \
```

Comment: On my keyboard to click the + key I just type the + key. Any idea how to adapt this accordingly? Thanks

Comment: I added another possibility.

Comment: Actually, that last option did the trick. In my case: !+SC00C::Send, / From another forum got perhaps a more elegant solution: !++::Send, / (the first + is Shift, the second + sign)

Comment: The other solution might stop working with new versions of AutoHotKey. I think the SC00C option is safer.