# How do I keep FN Lock locked after reboot/restart on a Samsung laptop?

Tags: boot, fn-key, samsung-laptop

For some reason, my Samsung NP270E5E (ATIV Book 2) laptop
does not keep my <kbd>Fn</kbd> function locked after I restart the laptop.
(Running Windows 10, all drivers up to date.)
I've tried pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn Lock</kbd>, but to no avail. 
Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your keyboard has a dedicated <kbd>Fn Lock</kbd> key:

[image]

Use this key to keep the Fn function locked.

Otherwise, your keyboard may have an <kbd>Fn Lock</kbd> that appears as a
secondary action on another key. You will need in this case to hold
<kbd>Fn</kbd> and press that Lock key.
To disable, hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> and press that key again.

In the below example, the Lock function is found on the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key:

[image]

Comment: The thing is, I know that the button exists. It works, but it resets back to its original state (fn lock off) after I restart.

Comment: You could use a [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script to simulate pressing the Fn Lock key, and schedule it to execute on login. Use the procedure in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1493252/8672) to find the key-code of this key. If the key does not have a key-code, then it's handled by the keyboard itself and there is no solution (unless the manufacture supplies some utility for setting the default state).

Answer (score 1):

Check your BIOS settings.  There may be a setting to set function lock enabled at boot.

Comment: It's not there, already checked. This may pertain to Dell laptops rather than Samsung laptops.